# Ошибки при обновлении npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Появляются ошибки в консоли при обновлении npm

> npm i -g npm

[Лог-файл](https://vk.com/doc88174639_454092635) приложен

Comment: что означает npm i -g npm ? особенно интересует второй npm?

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть **в самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте с sudo

```
sudo npm install -g   или  npm install -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Ваша ссылка на логи устарела.
Могу предположить, что не хватает прав установить npm.

UNIX-системы:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/746102/455418

```
sudo npm install -g   или  npm install -g
```

Windows-системы:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412129/how-can-i-update-npm-on-windows

Перейдите в установочную директорию, например `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`. Запустите установку без флага:

```
npm install npm
```

Если это не помогло, запустите консоль от имени администратора.